# Rails _url methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a controller in rails using `./script/generate controller the_name create`

Then in my view I have a `link_to "Link text", the_name_url`

I get `undefined local variable or method 'the_name'`

Shouldn't this work?

Comment: can you post both the view and controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any references to the_name (without url or path) in your code. Also make sure that you have added an appropriate named route to config/routes.rb.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't added the correct route. Try something like:

```
map.resources :things
```